# slim file is not executing the js inside it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, jeditable, slim-lang

i am using gem 'jeditable-rails' in my rails 3.2 application for inplace editting
In my controller, i have

```
def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
render :layout => false if request.xhr?
end
```

ANd in my articles/update.js.slim

i have

```
- unless @article.errors.empty?
  | $("#error_msg").html(@article.errors);
- else
  | $("#success_msg").html("updated successfully");
```

But when i do an update it updates and going to the js file and renders it like as it is.
like `$("#error_msg").html(@comment.errors);` is printed as such or `$("#success_msg").html("updated successfully")`

EDIT :

i am using the jeditable plugin for edit in place for my article title alone. It updates the article title and renders the js file as it is

the response which i got here is json. how to resolve this. GIve  suggestions

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, but I'll try to guess and suggest you to debug your javascript as in [this article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/).

Comment: Please describe your question more explicitly, since I don't get your point.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `|` pipe tells the Slim rendering engine to output the content as text, hence why you are literally seeing it print your JavaScript code as text.

In this case, I don't think you want or need to use Slim here. Using ERB would be just fine. Try replacing the `articles/update.js.slim` file with `articles/update.js.erb` instead with the following code:

```
var valid = <%= @article.errors.empty? %>;

if (valid) {
  $("#success_msg").html("updated successfully");
}
else {
  $("#error_msg").html("<%= escape_javascript(@article.errors) %>");
}
```

Comment: i am getting Missing template article/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :coffee]}. error i added the file update.js.erb in my views/articles/

Comment: Hm, your initial file was definitely named `article.js.slim` correct? I'm not sure how it would have been rendering that file for a :json request in the first place. Because the request is in :json format, I would imagine that it's expecting an `articles/update.json` template.